# ASP.NET MVC (default template) - OWIN creates each class two times per request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I've created a new ASP.NET MVC (5 I guess) project with default template.

In *Startup.Auth.cs* at the beginning of method *ConfigureAuth* OWIN is used to create the EF DataContext and also UserManager and SignInManager for ASP.NET Identity. Its commented there by MS that all of this classes are created **once per request** but that's not what's happening.

When I start the web application ApplicationDbContext, ApplicationUserManager and ApplicationSignInManager are created and get disposed at the end of the request. But after the page is completely loaded in browser OWIN again creates instances of the classes and "does something". What's the reason for this? In my opinion the request has ended well because I can see the rendered page so what's OWIN doing here?

Comment: Is it just yet another request from your browser?

Comment: Looking with F12 Tools I can see only one GET request to the page. However after the page is fully loaded there are more GET requests with "browserlink" stuff in it. There is no second GET request to the page. I'm new to ASP so I dont' know if the browserlink feature can be the reason for OWIN to create all the stuff a second time.

Comment: Browserlink is an auxiliary stuff that connects your VS to the browser. Could you disable it please and verify if the issue is gone?

Comment: You were right. Activated Browserlink Feature was the reason why there was a 2nd request. Thanks.